# MySQLi Prepare Statement not Inserting into Database Table

Tags: php, mysqli, prepared-statement

I'm attempting to use MySQLi prepare statement to insert values into my OpenJobs table.  I have 4 checkboxes equating to 4 different jobs.  If one or more checkbox is marked, I want the corresponding jobid inserted into the table.  Here's the code I've written thus far:

```
<form id="frmSelStore" method="post" action ="<?php 
$restaurantid = $_POST['ddlStore'];
$jobtype = $_POST['jobs'];
if($stmt = mysqli_prepare($mysqli,'Insert into OpenJobs values $restaurantid, $jobtype'))
{
    mysqli_stmt_bind_param($restaurantid,$jobtype);
    mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
    echo '$jobtype was posted for Store $restaurantid';
    mysqli_stmt_close($stmt);
}

?>">
```

Rest of form:

```
 <fieldset><?php 
    $query=('SELECT restaurantid,location from restaurant');
    $result = mysqli_query($mysqli,$query);
    echo '<select name="ddlStore">';
    while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result))
    {
        echo '<option value="' . htmlspecialchars($row['restaurantid']) . '">' .
         htmlspecialchars($row['location']) . 
        '</option>';
    }
    echo '</select>';
    ?>
    <h2>Step 2:  Please Select the Jobs to be Posted</h2>
    <input type="checkbox" name='[jobs]' id="cbJobs1">Host/Hostess
    </input><br/>
    <input type="checkbox" name='[jobs]' id="cbJob2">Bartender</input><br/>
    <input type="checkbox" name='[jobs]' id="cbJob3">Server</input><br/>
    <input type="checkbox" name='[jobs]' id="cbJobs4">Cook</input><br/>

    <input type="submit" id="submit"/>
    </fieldset>
```

When I select a checkbox and click Submit, I would expect to get the message echoed that my jobs had been posted.  However, nothing occurs and no records are written to the table.  How do I remedy this?

Update:  I've polished my code a bit as follows:

```
<form id="frmSelStore" method="post" action ="<?php 
$restaurantid = $_POST['ddlStore'];
$jobtype = $_POST['jobs'];
$stmt = mysqli_statement_init($mysqli);
if(mysqli_stmt_prepare($stmt,'Insert into `OpenJobs` (`restaurantid`,`jobtype`) 
values ($restaurantid, $jobtype'))
{
mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt,$restaurantid,$jobtype);
mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
printf("%d Row Inserted.\n", mysqli_stmt_affected_rows($stmt));
mysqli_stmt_close($stmt);
}

?>">
```

When I view my page, I see the following errors:

```
Warning</b>: mysqli_stmt_bind_param() expects 
parameter 1 to be mysqli_stmt, null given in 
<b>/path/to/page</b> on line 
<b>23</b><br /><br /><b>Warning</b>: mysqli_stmt_execute() expects parameter 1 to be   
mysqli_stmt, boolean given in <b>/path/to/page</b> 
on line <b>24</b><br />$jobtype was posted for Store   
$restaurantid<br /><b>Warning</b>:   
mysqli_stmt_close() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_stmt, boolean given in 
<b>/path/to/page</b> on line <b>26</b><br /> was not 
found on this server.

Additionally, a 404 Not Found error was encountered while trying to use an 
ErrorDocument to handle the request.
```

I'm following the manual examples of the procedural method but need a bit of guidance in how to remedy the above errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems as though your insert query statement is malformed.

Try changing:

```
Insert into OpenJobs values $restaurantid, $jobtype
```

Minimally To:

```
Insert into OpenJobs values ($restaurantid, $jobtype)
```

My Suggestion:

```
insert into `OpenJobs` (`restaurantid`, `jobtype`) values ($restaurantid, $jobtype)
```

**Please note:** Case sensitivity can also cause problems depending on how you have things configured (e.g. OpenJobs vs. openJobs vs. openjobs).

Comment: I used your third suggestion as follows: if($stmt = mysqli_prepare($mysqli,'Insert into `OpenJobs` (`restaurantid`,`jobtype`) values $restaurantid, $jobtype'));
However the same result occurs.

Comment: You are still missing parenthesis around your `values`. You should have `values ($restaurantid, $jobtype)`.